# Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'WIN2016\mssqlUser', error code 0x80090304 After creating new user only

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, windows-authentication

I've added `Ubuntu 20.04` under a Active Directory Domain Controller and after I create a new User subsequent queries fails with error

```
1> CREATE LOGIN JohnyBonzela WITH PASSWORD = '***#'
2> GO
1> CREATE LOGIN JohnyBonzela1 WITH PASSWORD = '***#'
2> GO
Msg 15404, Level 16, State 22, Server mssql-ubuntu, Line 1
Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'WIN2016\mssqlUser', error code 0x80090304.
```

Note: first create account was worked well and the problem occurred for subsequent query execution

I found this MS article but no luck with it too https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/error-15404-could-not-obtain-information-about-windows-nt-group/ba-p/1027461

Here is my `key tab` file entries

```
user@mssql-ubuntu:~$ sudo klist -kt /var/opt/mssql/secrets/mssql.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:/var/opt/mssql/secrets/mssql.keytab
KVNO Timestamp         Principal
---- ----------------- --------------------------------------------------------
   2 06/25/21 12:31:13 MSSQLSvc/mssql-ubuntu.WIN2016.LOCAL:1433@WIN2016.LOCAL
   2 06/25/21 12:31:13 MSSQLSvc/mssql-ubuntu.WIN2016.LOCAL:1433@WIN2016.LOCAL
   2 06/25/21 12:31:13 MSSQLSvc/mssql-ubuntu:1433@WIN2016.LOCAL
   2 06/25/21 12:31:13 MSSQLSvc/mssql-ubuntu:1433@WIN2016.LOCAL
   2 06/25/21 12:31:13 mssqlUser@WIN2016.LOCAL
   2 06/25/21 12:31:13 mssqlUser@WIN2016.LOCAL
   2 06/25/21 12:31:13 mssql-ubuntu@WIN2016.LOCAL
   2 06/25/21 12:31:13 mssql-ubuntu@WIN2016.LOCAL
user@mssql-ubuntu:~$ sudo klist -kt /etc/krb5.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Timestamp         Principal
---- ----------------- --------------------------------------------------------
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 restrictedkrbhost/mssql-ubuntu.win2016.local@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 restrictedkrbhost/MSSQL-UBUNTU@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 restrictedkrbhost/mssql-ubuntu.win2016.local@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 restrictedkrbhost/MSSQL-UBUNTU@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 restrictedkrbhost/mssql-ubuntu.win2016.local@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 restrictedkrbhost/MSSQL-UBUNTU@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 restrictedkrbhost/mssql-ubuntu.win2016.local@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 restrictedkrbhost/MSSQL-UBUNTU@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 restrictedkrbhost/mssql-ubuntu.win2016.local@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 restrictedkrbhost/MSSQL-UBUNTU@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 host/mssql-ubuntu.win2016.local@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 host/MSSQL-UBUNTU@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 host/mssql-ubuntu.win2016.local@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 host/MSSQL-UBUNTU@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 host/mssql-ubuntu.win2016.local@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 host/MSSQL-UBUNTU@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 host/mssql-ubuntu.win2016.local@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 host/MSSQL-UBUNTU@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 host/mssql-ubuntu.win2016.local@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 host/MSSQL-UBUNTU@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 MSSQL-UBUNTU$@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 MSSQL-UBUNTU$@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:19 MSSQL-UBUNTU$@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:20 MSSQL-UBUNTU$@WIN2016.LOCAL
   1 06/17/21 22:15:20 MSSQL-UBUNTU$@WIN2016.LOCAL
```

I need to always relogin to MsSQL Server only after `CREATE LOGIN`? Any thoughts why it happens.. does this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/error-15404-could-not-obtain-information-about-windows-nt-group/ba-p/1027461) make any sense?

**P.S.** : KVNO for `mssql.keytab` is shown as `2` while KVNO for `krb5.keytab` is `1`. does it make any differences here?

The User created from Domain Controller has following accesses

```
CREATE LOGIN [WIN2016\mssqlUser] FROM WINDOWS;
 ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [WIN2016\mssqlUser];    
GO
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, is it possible to try to do login in this format: `mssqlUser@win2016.local`?

Comment: Login to DB? Or a machine?

Comment: Please, try to add or login in both in the format above and not `DOMAIN\user`; after test, please, give a feedback.

Comment: ```CREATE LOGIN [mssqlUser@win2016.local] FROM WINDOWS;                        Msg 15407, Level 16, State 1, Server mssql-ubuntu, Line 1
'mssqlUser@win2016.local' is not a valid Windows NT name. Give the complete name: <domain\username>.```

Comment: And Login to machine ```ssh mssqlUser@win2016.local@1xx.x.x.x``` would persist the original error ```Msg 15404, Level 16, State 22, Server mssql-ubuntu, Line 1
Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'WIN2016\mssqlUser', error code 0x80090304.```